# Continuous at a point implies bounded on an interval containing that point

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a function differentiable any number of times on some open interval containing $a$, and let $$P_n(h)=\sum^n_{r=0}\dfrac{f^{(r)}(a)}{r!}h^r$$ be the $n^{\rm th}$ Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$. Prove that for any $n\geqslant1$, $$\dfrac{f(a+h)-P_n(h)}{h^n}\to0 \ \text{ as } \ h\to0\,;$$ and that $P_n$ is the only polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$ that has this property.
>
> ---
>
> The form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem tell us that the expression we have to show tends to $0$ is equal to $hf^{(n+1)}(a+\theta h)/(n+1)!$ for some $\theta\in(0,1)$ (depending on $h$). But $f^{(n+1)}$ is differentiable, hence continuous, at $a$, $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{so}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{it}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{is}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{bounded}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{on}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{some}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{interval}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{containing}}}}$ $\color{green}{\underline{\color{black}{\text{$a$}}}}$. So for $h$ small enough, $\left|hf^{(n+1)}(a+\theta h)/(n+1)!\right|\leqslant $ (some constant) $|h|$, so it $\to0$ as $h\to0$ by the Sandwich theorem. If $Q_n(h)$ were another polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$ with the property $S_h(h)/h^n\to0$ as $h\to0$, which is impossible unless $S_n\equiv0$ (check this carefully!).

What theorem is being used for the part of the solution highlighted in green?

Comment: Every function continuous in a closed interval $[a,b]$ is bounded in that interval. One can view this as a consequence of the fact that $[a,b]$ is compact. The result is sometimes called the *Boundedness Theorem** but that name is not much used. You have probably seen a version that says the function attains a maximum and minimum.

Comment: How do we know that the function is continuous on a closed interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $a$, exists $\delta > 0 $ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(a)| < 1$, say. However, we have that: $$|f(x)| - |f(a)| \leq |f(x) - f(a)| < 1 \implies |f(x)| < 1 + |f(a)|$$
for all $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$, hence $f$ is locally bounded.